# Cassandra Authentication error in creating a new users

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

I'm running cassandra in 4 nodes those 4 nodes are in one cluster.Now I want to make one node as Password authenticator.I have made the required changes in cassandra.yaml file and restarted the cassandra. Now it got created the new user CASSANDRA i have logged into the cassandra with those details.In that i want to create another new user for my convenience. After giving the create user command im getting the error as below,**More over im doing these process in Linux environment**.please help me to fix this issue.Thanks in Advance.

> ServerError: ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level LOCAL_ONE">

Comment: This generally happens if you change the snitch settings. It's a inconsitency between your replication configuration and snitch.

Comment: So,what changes that I need to do,inorder to create new users.

Comment: Solve the inconsistency. What's the name of your cluster in your snitch and what's the name in your replication configuration?

Comment: name of my cluster is 'New Cluster'.I didnt get the name of replication configuration.

Comment: have you changes the replication settings on the system_auth keyspace? by default this is set to SimpleStrategy 1. You should increase the replication on the keyspace and run a repair on it.

Comment: yeah i have changed the system_auth keyspace according to my datacenteres and racks.Now issue was resolved.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Initially the system_auth keyspace will have one replication factor,as mentioned below
**CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor': '1'};**
Now i have changed the system_auth keyspace according to my datacenter,i have 2 datacenters each have 2 nodes in it.So i altered the table as below,
**alter KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = { 'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy','DC1': '2','DC2': '2'};** 
This fixed my issue and was able to create users in cassandra.